# Is it ok to start a sentence with "seems"?

Tags: grammar, formality

In a formal paper, would it be alright to include a sentence such as

"Seems as if the extremist Muslims are being highlighted by the media to perpetuate stereotypes"

or

"Seems that the media is exploiting the bad apples in the bunch to spoil the whole bag"

Maybe I have to include a word such as "it" or "there" before "seems"? Any answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, without the pronoun ("it"), the sentence is ungrammatical. The two examples you give are very informal in tone.

Furthermore, I would question if the use of "seems" is appropriate, as it weakens the assertion. Is the media *actually* perpetuating a stereotype, or does it only seem that way? If you think it is the former, say so. If the latter, you should qualify the assertion: to whom does it appear that the media is exploiting a stereotype? Otherwise the reader can only assume that it *seems* that way to *you*; you are merely stating your opinion and not an objective observation. In a formal paper, be forceful.

Answer (score 0):

No, that subjectless "seems" construction is only in informal speech.  A similar example is "Looks like rain". (Also, "alright" for "all right" is not good in formal writing.)